# How do I make an element fill remaining space unless it must wrap

Tags: html, css

I have two `div`s. I am trying to make one of them fill the remaining space, until it must wrap.

```css
#resize {
resize: both;
display: inline-block;
background: #0f0;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
}
#div1 {
display: inline-block;
background: #f00;
}
#div2 {
display: inline-block;
background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div id="resize">
  <div id="div1">div1</div>
  <div id="div2">div2 (remaining space)</div>
</div>
```

I can achieve the fill:

```css
#resize {
  resize: both;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #0f0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*fill*/
  display: flex
}

#div1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f00;
}

#div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #00f;
  /*fill*/
  flex-grow: 1
}
```

```html
<div id="resize">
  <div id="div1">div1</div>
  <div id="div2">div2 (remaining space)</div>
</div>
```

But I can't get the `div`s to wrap vertically when they overflow

Comment: use flex-wrap: wrap; in #resize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you allowed to use flex box, if yes then you can use below CSS to get the desired result

```
#resize {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 align-items: baseline;
 ...removed other CSS for readability
}

#div2 {
 flex: 1;
 min-width: 151px; //fixed min-width to wrap at certain width
 ...removed other CSS for readability
}
```

```css
#resize {
resize: both;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: baseline;
background: #0f0;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
}
#div1 {
display: inline-block;
background: #f00;
}
#div2 {
flex: 1;
min-width: 151px;
display: inline-block;
background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div id="resize">
  <div id="div1">div1</div>
  <div id="div2">div2 (remaining space)</div>
</div>
```